# Fetched data is not displaying properly in PHP

Tags: php

I am fetching data from database and I have to display data in design part. I am able to fetch the data from database according to the design. My fetched data contains fields `image`, `position`.

[image]

```
<?php 
$CompanyImages = $controller->ourcompany_Images();
foreach($CompanyImages as $OurCompanyImages) {
    if($OurCompanyImages['POSITION']==1){

    }
    else if($OurCompanyImages['POSITION']==2){}
    else if($OurCompanyImages['POSITION']==3){}
}
?>
```

Design:

```
<div class="row">

<?php 
$CompanyImages = $controller->ourcompany_Images();
foreach($CompanyImages as $OurCompanyImages) {
    if($OurCompanyImages['POSITION']==1){

    }
    else if($OurCompanyImages['POSITION']==2){}
    else if($OurCompanyImages['POSITION']==3){}
}
?>

<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="company-imgs wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0s"><img src="images/our-company-1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="company-right">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="company-imgs wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".2s"><img src="images/our-company-3.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="company-imgs wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".4s"><img src="images/our-company-2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
                    <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you want to do ? And what's not working?

Comment: i want to display data according to design

Comment: Is that image is a design you want?

Comment: i have to fetch it from database...image is coming dynamically..but i have 3 records in db.while fetching how to place 3 records as per design